# Error converting markdown into pdf in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

I can't convert markdown notebook into pdf but am able to convert code cell.

The error I got is :

```
500 : Internal Server Error
The error was:
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed

[I 10:32:16.940 NotebookApp] Running pdflatex 3 times: [u'pdflatex', u'notebook.tex']
[C 10:32:17.174 NotebookApp] pdflatex failed: [u'pdflatex', u'notebook.tex']
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
    entering extended mode
    (./notebook.tex
    LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
    Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
 tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

    LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.232 ...l the conduits, \$ \frac{\Delta P}{\mu L}
                                                      \$ are set to be 1.0
    ? 
    ! Emergency stop.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.232 ...l the conduits, \$ \frac{\Delta P}{\mu L}
                                                      \$ are set to be 1.0
    !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
    Transcript written on notebook.log.

[I 10:32:17.175 NotebookApp] Running bibtex 1 time: [u'bibtex', u'notebook']
[W 10:32:17.262 NotebookApp] bibtex had problems, most likely because there were no citations
[I 10:32:17.262 NotebookApp] Running pdflatex 3 times: [u'pdflatex', u'notebook.tex']
[C 10:32:17.501 NotebookApp] pdflatex failed: [u'pdflatex', u'notebook.tex']
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
    entering extended mode

    LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.232 ...l the conduits, \$ \frac{\Delta P}{\mu L}
                                                      \$ are set to be 1.0
    ? 
    ! Emergency stop.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.232 ...l the conduits, \$ \frac{\Delta P}{\mu L}
                                                      \$ are set to be 1.0
    !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
    Transcript written on notebook.log.

[W 10:32:17.503 NotebookApp] 500 GET /nbconvert/pdf/ComputerProject1.ipynb?download=true (::1): nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed
[E 10:32:17.505 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36", 
      "Host": "localhost:8888", 
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/ComputerProject1.ipynb", 
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    }
[E 10:32:17.505 NotebookApp] 500 GET /nbconvert/pdf/ComputerProject1.ipynb?download=true (::1) 787.74ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/ComputerProject1.ipynb
```

I have pandoc, mactex installed. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: That is not enough information. You may want at least copy paste the last few output lines of the server.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I copied some of the outputs from the server. But it looks messy

Comment: As you can see in the output you are using latex, but have a syntax error. That you have to figure out first.

Comment: I don't understand where is the syntax error. Newbie here.

Comment: I want to download the file into pdf and I used pdf via latex.

Comment: I could do this if the cells are code, but failed for markdown cells.